# Conditionally adding a define to a configuration .h file with CMake

Tags: configuration, cmake, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor

I know that you can generate `config.h` files with CMake processing a template, where whenever you write

```
#define FOO ${SOME_VARIABLE}
```

and in CMake you set `SOME_VARIABLE` to, say, 123, then you'll get

```
#define FOO 123
```

And that's great. But no I want `BAR` to be defined only conditionally, i.e. sometimes config.h will have

```
#define BAR
```

and sometimes it won't, not even to a null/default value. How can I do this with CMake?

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this is with:

```
#cmakedefine BOO
```

in the `configure.h` file template. This will be replaced with either

```
#define BAR whatever_it_is_defined_to_goes_here
```

or

```
/* #undef BAR */
```

depending on whether VAR is set in CMake to any value not considered a false constant by the if() command.

Cf. the CMake documentation [page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) on the `configure_file()` command.